# ActionbarSherlock in Android studio

Tags: android

After import ABS in Android studio, i can import and use all classes from ABS , like SherlockFragment etc.

But only custom theme got problem.

I want to create custom theme like:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

But android studio got error notice is:

no resource found match "Theme.Sherlock".

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio/16588104#16588104

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626818/android-studio-actionbar-sherlock-error-with-gradle?lq=1