# Android Studio update today with regression

Tags: gradle, android-studio

Started Android Studio today, and it popped up an update notice.  Since I'm eager to explore new features and bug fixes, I clicked yes.  Now the Project Structure dialog where you setup dependencies is missing, and has been replaced by a message:

> We will provide a UI to configure project settings later. Until then, please manually edit your build.gradle file(s.)

So, I go out to try to figure out how to add ActionBarSherlock to my project as a project dependency, and have hit a brick wall.  I have no idea how to import ActionBarSherlock project as a Library Project, and configure my project to use it. There isn't much documentation on this at Google, IntelliJ, and the Gradle docs assume a LOT of pre-existing knowledge of build systems.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of posts on SO how to do this (although referenced with already missing Project structure dialog)

[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

[Android-Studio ActionBar sherlock error with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626818/android-studio-actionbar-sherlock-error-with-gradle)

[Installing ActionbarSherlock with Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577241/installing-actionbarsherlock-with-android-studio)

[Problems importing project into Android Studio regarding ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577580/problems-importing-project-into-android-studio-regarding-actionbarsherlock)

In short:

1. Create a folder (i.e. /libraries) in  your root.
2. Extract actionbarsherlock there
3. Create a new file build.gradle in actionbarsherlock root with the following contents

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
       }
   }
   apply plugin: 'android-library'

   dependencies {
       compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
   }

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 17
       buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 7
       targetSdkVersion 16
   }

   sourceSets {
       main {
           manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
           java.srcDirs = ['src']
           resources.srcDirs = ['src']
           res.srcDirs = ['res']
       }
   }


   }
   ```
4. In your project's build.gradle

   ```
   dependencies {
       //NOTE that "libraries" is actually a folder name you created in step 1
       compile project(":libraries:actionbarsherlock")
       //Any other dependencies here
       //Make sure there is no android-support-v4.jar in this build file
       //as it is already contained in actionbarsherlock project
   }
   ```
5. In settings.gradle

   ```
   //NOTE that "libraries" is actually a folder name you created in step 1
   include ':libraries:actionbarsherlock', ':<Your project name>'
   ```

**EDIT**

**Last step:** Close your project and open it back again for Studio to pick up the Intelli-sense data

Comment: Your first link is invalid - It says to go to the Project Structure UI, which is now missing post-update. Your second link also makes no mention of WHICH gradle files to edit, again assuming I understand how  to use gradle. It's just a copy-paste from chapter 55 of the gradle docs.

Comment: I made a screencast of your instructions, followed to the letter: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYns7b2Plvw Still can't figure out how to actually USE actionbarsherlock once I have it built.

Comment: @NikMartin See update above. You could still use the library and compile/run your app with the steps above. It's just you had to do a project reload for Android Studio to pick up the dependency changes you made in the gradle file. Hope this helps now

Comment: @NikMartin, although the above links do reference Projects structure UI, they contain information that may help you figure out how to do stuff.

Comment: Alas I have thrown in the towel.  I deleted Android Studio and reinstalled InrelliJ Community Edition with Android Plug-ins. Android Studio just isn't ready for use except for testing IMO. The final straw was closing the project and reopening when Android Studio popped up a dialog telling me it was deleting BOTH my projects because they were un-used.

Comment: @NikMartin, without doubt, Android Studio is really raw right now. It's connectivity with the actual build system is still in a poor state. I've moved to completely using CLI to build and run the project and using Studio just for code editing :)